# Circle around the mouse? In three.js

Tags: three.js

When I Move mouse over an object it flies. How to make that object came off the circle? Radius is 100, I added a circle to the mouse.

Here is my code:

```js
function onDocumentMouseMove(event){
    fly.style.left = (event.clientX - maxR) + 'px';
    fly.style.top = (event.clientY - maxR) + 'px';
    event.preventDefault();
    mouse.x = (( event.clientX / renderer.domElement.width ) * 2 - 1);
    mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / renderer.domElement.height ) * 2 + 1;
    raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );
    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children );
    if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
        new TWEEN.Tween( intersects[ 0 ].object.position ).to( {
            x: Math.random()*750-375,
            y: Math.random()*750-375,
            /*z: Math.random() * 400 - 200 */}, 10000 )
        .easing( TWEEN.Easing.Elastic.Out).start()
    }
}
```

Comment: What flies, not sure what you asking...., you want something to circle around the mouse current position?